# Ternary in Laravel Blade

Tags: laravel, ternary-operator, laravel-blade

Looking for a ternary operator for blade templates

```
@if(Auth::check()) ? yes : no @endif
```

Can't seem to get it to work this works

```
@if(Auth::check()) yes @else no @endif
```

suppose there is not much in it for this example, just curious.

Comment: Can we nest ternary operator in laravel blade, As it is giving error unexpected '['

Answer (score 127):

You are free to use it with `{{ }}`.

```
{{ Auth::check() ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```

Answer (score 64):

This works:

```
{{ Auth::check() ? 'yes' : 'no' }}
```

Comment: And how can I add anchor within it? `{{ Auth::check() ? '<a href=#>Logout</a>' : '<a href=login>Login</a>' }}` prints it as it is.

Comment: You need to allow escaped input. In Laravel 4 use `{{{ }}}`, and in Laravel 5 use `{!! !!}`

Comment: Awesome. While I can still use `{{}}` in L5, it seems it does not work for all cases anymore.

Comment: `{{ }}`  is for escaped output - which is what you should use 99% of the time. You should only use `{!! !!}` when you want to have non-escaped output - which should be very rare

Answer (score 31):

I know this question was asked a while ago, but this may help somebody.

You can now do this in Laravel 5.

```
{{ $variable or "default" }}
```

[Laravel 5 Blade Templates](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates#other-blade-control-structures)

[Laravel 5.2 Blade Template](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/blade#displaying-data)

Comment: I miss doing similar things in JS natively, while Php complains on undefined variable instead. This is a cool addition to blade at least.

Comment: FYI - this is going to be removed in Laravel `5.5` - or at least not supported anymore. Taylor says to use `{{ $variable ?? "default" }}` which is supported by PHP7 (which 5.5 requires)

Comment: `{{ $variable or "default" }}` is working for 5 to 5.5.28 may be they provide backward compatibility

Comment: OR operator is deprecated in Laravel 5.5+. Use ?? instead: {{ $foo ?? 'nothing there' }}

Answer (score 22):

in addition, here is a nice shortcut `?:`, if you you need to print some variable's value or if it's empty some default text

```
{{ $value ?: 'Default Value' }}
```

Comment: Is this the same as "or" stated in Bryces answer?

Comment: @KevinRedman yes, it's the same, I'd say 'or' is a preferable way when you don't know if $value is actually set

Answer (score 22):

For Laravel 5 + php7, you should be using the null coalesce operator as explained in [this Laravel News article](https://laravel-news.com/blade-templates-null-coalesce-operator), like so:

```
{{ $value ?? "Fallback" }}
```

> Before the null coalescing operator, Blade handled the same problem with the “or” operator, which allows a default value when the first value isn’t set, separated by an “or”.

Answer (score 1):

The ternary conditions look like this:
{{ condition ? 'yes' : 'no' }}

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since another user already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

**core php**

```
if(!empty($mat->getSupplier))    {
echo $mat->getSupplier->supplier_name;
}
else if(!empty($mat->request_plant)    {
echo \App\PlantName::whereId($mat->request_plant)->value('name');
}
else    {
echo $mat->other_supplier;
}
```

**laravel blade file**

```
 {{ (!empty($mat->getSupplier)) ? $mat->getSupplier->supplier_name : ((!empty($mat->request_plant)) ? \App\PlantName::whereId($mat->request_plant)->value('name'): $mat->other_supplier) }}
```