# Php use ternary operator in for loop

Tags: php, for-loop, conditional-statements, laravel-blade

For can I use a ternary Operator in a for Loop?

I am using laravel blade Syntax that is why the condition Looks like this (@for, @else,@end)

```
<?php
@for($i = 0; $i < isset($Count) ? $Count : 0; $i++)
@else
@end
```

Comment: have  a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25284344/ternary-in-laravel-blade

Comment: what's the issue ? do you have any errors ?

Answer (score 2):

use it like this

```
<?php
@for($i = 0; $i <(isset($Count) ? $Count : 0); $i++)
@else
@end
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php) `?:` is left associative which means that everything left to `?` is used as the condition and everything left of `:` and right of `?` is used as the true result so `$i < isset($Count) ? $Count : 0` means `($i < isset($count)?$count:0`

If that's not what you want you need to enclose what you want done first in `()` e.g. `$i < (isset($Count) ? $Count : 0)` is probably what you need.

Overall using parenthesis is usually a good idea, they cost next to nothing and can make you extra certain on what's happening.