# if data exist submit button turn into update function (Laravel)

Tags: laravel, forms

[image: form]

i have this form, what i wanted to do is if the data for this id is exist, my submit button turn into update function.

i still use store data function for my controller because i didnt know how to do the logic.

```
 public function store(Request $request)
{
      $request->validate([
        'title'             => 'required',
        'description'       => 'required',
        'category_page_id'  => 'required',
      ]);

      $seo = new Seo;
      $seo->category_page_id = $request->input('category_page_id');
      $seo->title            = $request->input('title') ?? '';
      $seo->description      = $request->input('description');
      $seo->save();


    return back()->withStatus(__('SEO successfully updated.'));
}
```

and this is the form for my update function

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('seo.update') }}" autocomplete="off">
                    @csrf
                    @method('put')

                    <h3 class="heading-small mb-4">{{ __('PAGE SEO') }}</h3>

                    @if (session('status'))
                        <div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible fade show" role="alert">
                            {{ session('status') }}
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    @endif

                    <div class="pl-lg-4">
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('category_page_id') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                            <div class="form-group form-box">
                                <label for="category_page_id">Page</label>
                                <select class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('category_page_id') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" name="category_page_id">
                                @foreach ($categorypages->slice(0, 1) as $key => $value)
                                    <option value="{{ $value->id }}" @if (old('category_page_id') == $value->id) {{ 'selected' }} @endif>{{ $value->name }}</option>
                                @endforeach
                                </select>
                                @error('category_page_id')
                                <small class="text-red">{{ $message }}</small>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                            <label class="form-control-label" for="input-title">{{ __('SEO Title') }}</label>
                            <input type="text" name="title" id="input-title" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('title') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('title') }}" value="{{ old('title', $seo->title) }}" required autofocus>

                            @if ($errors->has('title'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('title') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' has-danger' : '' }}">
                            <label class="form-control-label" for="input-description">{{ __('Description') }}</label>
                            <input type="description" name="description" id="input-description" class="form-control form-control-alternative{{ $errors->has('description') ? ' is-invalid' : '' }}" placeholder="{{ __('Description') }}" value="{{ old('description', $seo->description) }}" required>

                            @if ($errors->has('email'))
                                <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                    <strong>{{ $errors->first('email') }}</strong>
                                </span>
                            @endif
                        </div>

                        <div class="text-center">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success mt-4">{{ __('Save') }}</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
```

what can i do to resolve my problem? is there any way to do this properly?

Comment: provide the controller that returns the view what that form and provide that view

Comment: @lagbox okay i'll edit it a sec

Comment: i put my form blade in my question, please take a look @lagbox

Comment: and the controller method that is returning this view

Comment: May be you can run a ternary condition to set the label of the value! If the object isn't empty then you can set it to update or else set it to save.

Comment: @lagbox i edited it, its public function store code

Comment: @PrathameshKoshti so i should check if the id is not empty than its function in controller should be the update?

Comment: provide the code of the controller method that returns that view

Comment: @ErandaDava yes right check if the id is present or not it would be easier to write the condition.

Comment: Or may be you can see here how to write ternary condition in the blade file https://stackoverflow.com/a/25284391/4601544

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do

```
   @if($seo_data != null) //here you can check the data is present or not 

    <form action="{{ route('seo_data.store')" method="post" >
      @csrf
      <input type="text" value="{{ isset($seo_data) ? $seo_data->title : '' }}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">submit </button>
  </form>

  @else //if data is present then it goes to here

  <form action="{{ route('seo_data.update',encrypt($seo_data->id))" method="post">
      @csrf
      @method('PATCH')
      <input type="text" value="{{ isset($seo_data) ? $seo_data->title : '' }}">
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update </button>
  </form>
 @endif
```

otherwise if you dont want to hit anther route then check it into store function